# How can i perform auto close in firefox when download is complete

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, imacros

Any idea to close *firefox* when download is finished, like with any *imacros* script or any other *firefox* addon/extension? I tried to search on google and i only got all answer related to shutdown pc when download is finished
So any method, script or extension out there?

Comment: Use curl to do all downloads?

Comment: sorry what? :/ it's just a simple download not with curl

Comment: Did you try `TAB CLOSE` ?

Comment: yep now and it's working just need to configure a settings in firefox :) [ about:config>>browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab = false ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add at the end of your imacro code:

```
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
TAB CLOSE
```

Comment: i got that by the way thanks and add this ine to- configure a settings in firefox :) [ about:config>>browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab = false ]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the in-built iimClose([timeout])

More info here http://wiki.imacros.net/iimClose